# Regex for NLP rules

Tags: java, regex, nlp

I need to come up with several regular expressions for some natural language processing rules. I am a beginner in Java so some direction would be useful and good enough for me to come up with expressions for the rest of the rules. The rule is as follows:

```
.... such NP as {NP ,}* {(or | and)} NP
```

e.g. ... works by such authors as Herrick,
Goldsmith, and Shakespeare.

Here NP is a noun chunk in a sentence which I get from:

```
for (NLChunk chunk : sentence.getChunks()){
                if(chunk.getType().equals("NP")...rest of regex here)
```

Comment: What is the NLP package?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not using any package. Trying to make this purely context based.